# WIX create folder using property

Tags: wix, wix3.5

In the WIX I have a dialog where the user could select a folder [CUSTOM_FOLDER] from local machine, after the setup is finish I must give share to that folder and copy some files to it.
How could I archive this using WIX 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFTER the setup is finished you want to install more files?  Why not just simply install them during the process.  That point aside, you can create as many empty folders as your heart desires during the installation process, then using CustomAction elements you can add the files after the installation has completed successfully.  As for "give share to that folder" I have no idea what you are talking about. Please expand on that and I will try my best to answer it.

Comment: During the setup the user must be able to configure a folder where to copy some files, and that folder must be made public share in local network, after the setup is finish other user from local network must be able to access that folder.

Comment: From what I know WIX permit folder only under TARGETDIR and for this if I have TARGETDIR (c:\\) then I could not create and give permission to a folder from (d:\\), because is not under TARGETDIR.

Comment: WiX actually allows you to install to multiple drives it just takes a bit of creativity. See the following link for details.  http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg24928.html